# Mortar and pestle (pound or grind)

Tags: word-usage

If we put something in the "mortar" and beat it with a pestle, what will sound natural,  if we're talking about :"cookies", "herbs"?

> I am pounding/grinding the cookies.
>
> I am pounding the herbs.

So can both "pound" or "grind" be used for "cookies " (I guess "grind" doesn't sound quite right with "herbs"?) I mean "pound" means beating something (with something hard, preferably with a hammer, in case of food)

Comment: [***Mortar and pestle***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+pestle+and+mortar%2Ca+mortar+and+pestle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20pestle%20and%20mortar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20mortar%20and%20pestle%3B%2Cc0) is one of those collocations (like ***fish and chips, coach and horses, bricks and mortar***) that nearly always occurs in *one specific sequence*. But as my NGram link shows, a century ago the sequence for *that* one was usually ***pestle and mortar***.

Comment: Um.. I didn't quite get you @FumbleFingers. What exactly do you mean? (I mean is the word order required?)And are my sentences natural?

Comment: So what do you think @FumbleFingers

Comment: Well, I don't know why you would pound/grind ***cookies*** (people do talk about ***crumbling*** biscuits / cookies to make the base for a cheesecake, but pounding / grinding is a bit excessive for that). But I was just pointing out that the sequence ***mortar and pestle*** in your question title isn't very idiomatic today. Me personally, I tend to use ***pulverise*** to describe the action of mashing up things like garlic and herb leaves in a pestle and mortar. But ***pound*** is fine there. You ***grind*** big particles into smaller particles, and ***pound*** solids into [semi-]liquid form.

Comment: But @FumbleFingers I want cookies in a "ground" form. And you said "pound" will be used for "converting solids into semi-liquid form, but that won't happen with cookies. " So will it be "grind" or simply "crumble " be used(I mean I'm not doing it with my hands, I'm using the "pestle")

Comment: With a "pounder" (hammer) we can "pound" meat, but it only softens... So can "pound" be just for the action of "pounding"? (Beating with the pestle in my context...)

Comment: I'm not a cook, and I've no idea what you're trying to make, or exactly what consistency you're trying to reduce the cookies to. Come to that, I don't know what *you* mean by "cookie". We don't use that term so often in my native *British* English, but when we *do* use it, a "cookie" usually contains significant amounts of fat and perhaps semi-dried fruit, so if you mashed it up in a pestle and mortar you'd end up with something a bit like putty or Blu-Tac. I doubt that's what *you* mean, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers , "cookie" -----> "Biscuit". (So I have to crush it to a powdery consistency)

Comment: *Pounding* and *grinding* are two different things. However, there is no reason that they have to be mutually exclusive. If you are using a mortar and pestle, you can be thought to be both pounding *and* grinding something. Pounding it is the initial action, grinding it is the result. This is no different than saying that you *shot* somebody ***and*** *killed* them. But I'm not sure if that addresses your question at all. Are you only asking about cookies and herbs—and how one or the other action applies to them? (I don't see what the object has to do with the action.)